# Open a Datepicker calender

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

First of all, I want to apologise for my bad English. 
My question: 
 I'm programming a booking site for a hotel and I want to do a text field where you can choose one date of the dropping down calendar as the start and one text field where you can choose of course the date for the end.

How can I do this dropping down calendar, which gives me the date as a text?

AirBnB Example :

[image]

Comment: I'm using jQuery Datepicker for that [https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: @Hrvoje Krizic please check this [http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples) its helpful for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the daterangepicker http://www.daterangepicker.com ,maybe help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Pikaday** which is a pure JavaScript component. The result looks like this:

```js
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: new Date(2017, 11, 31),
    yearRange: [1950,2017]
});
```

```css
.example{
    margin-top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dbushell.com/Pikaday/css/pikaday.css">
<div class="example">
    <label for="datepicker">Date:</label>   
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</div>
<script src="https://dbushell.com/Pikaday/pikaday.js"></script>
```

You can customize it by looking at the full documentation [Here](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday).

Answer (score 1):

can use jquery,

```js
var startDate="";
var endDate="";
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
         var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, startDate);
         var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, endDate);
         var isHightlight =
            date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2));
        if(isHightlight && date1.getTime()==date.getTime()){
               return [true, "start-range"]
        }
        else if(isHightlight && date2.getTime()==date.getTime()){
               return [true, "end-range"]
        }
        return [true, isHightlight ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, startDate);
        var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, endDate);
        var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);

        if (!date1 || date2) {
            startDate=dateText;
            endDate="";
            FillTextBoxes();
        } else if (selectedDate < date1) {
           endDate=startDate;
           startDate=dateText;
       FillTextBoxes();
        } else {
             endDate=dateText;
              $("#input2").val(endDate);
        }

        $(this).datepicker();
    }
});
function FillTextBoxes(){
            $("#input1").val(startDate);
            $("#input2").val(endDate);
}
```

```css
       .start-range .ui-state-default {
          background: #16F2A5;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
       .dp-highlight .ui-state-default {
            background: #484;
            color: #FFF;
        }

        .end-range .ui-state-default{
         background: #F21663;
         color: #FFF;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>
  Dates:
  <label><b>To:</b></label>
  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <label><b>From:</b></label>
  <input type="text" id="input2">
</p>
<div class="datepicker"></div>
```